# GetModuleInformation Fails on Linkage in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, g++, psapi

I am trying to create a DLL Injector that will directly execute functions within the DLL in the target process. I am trying to get the entry point of the DLL I injected so I can get the offset of the function. I read on the Microsoft Docs to use `GetModuleInfo()`. I used the header `psapi.h` and found that compilation worked, but it failed on linkage providing the following error:

> g++ dll_injector.cpp -o dll_injector.exe

```
C:\Users\DELKAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOeKdhW.o:dll_injector.cpp:(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `GetModuleInformation@16'
C:\Users\DELKAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOeKdhW.o:dll_injector.cpp:(.text+0x1ae): undefined reference to `GetModuleInformation@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have already tried putting `Psapi.lib` in the same directory as `dll_injector.cpp` and then compiling with

> g++ dll_injector.cpp -o dll_injector.exe -Xlinker -L Psapi.lib

but it still threw the same error.

Here is the `dll_injector.cpp` code:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <psapi.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    DWORD pid;
    const char* dll_path = "C:\\Users\\Delkarix\\Desktop\\target_dll.dll";
    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, "C:\\Users\\Delkarix\\Desktop\\target_process.exe");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

    LPVOID addr = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, strlen(dll_path) + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, addr, dll_path, strlen(dll_path) + 1, NULL);
    CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE(GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary("kernel32"), "LoadLibraryA")), addr, 0, NULL);

    HMODULE lib = LoadLibrary("target_dll.dll");
    FARPROC proc_addr = GetProcAddress(lib, "test_function");

    MODULEINFO info;
    MODULEINFO info_current;
    BOOL success1 = GetModuleInformation(GetCurrentProcess(), lib, &info_current, sizeof(info_current));
    BOOL success2 = GetModuleInformation(hProcess, lib, &info, sizeof(info));
    cout << success1 << endl; // Test if it works
    cout << success2 << endl; // Test if it works
}
```

Here is the `target_dll.cpp` code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void test_function() {
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

I expect `dll_injector.exe` to print values that say if the functions succeed or not. I will change the code later so I will be able to get the entry point values. For now, I just want the functions to succeed without having to create a Visual Studio C++ Console Project. My question: Why is the linkage failing, and how can I get the linkage to succeed?

Comment: Try linking with `kernel32.lib` as the msdn documentation specifies that as well

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation) says that the function is in the `kernel32.dll` and you need to link with `kernel32.lib`.

Comment: Also note that the `-L` option is to add a *directory* to the library search path. The `-l` (lower-case L) option is to link with a specific library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

> g++ dll_injector.cpp -o dll_injector.exe -Xlinker -L Psapi.lib

to

> g++ dll_injector.cpp -o dll_injector.exe -L. -lPsapi

**-L(library path)** - specify a lib directory.  `.` specify current path.

**-l(library)** - link with library.  `Psapi` specify the name of library.(Omit suffix name of `.lib` in windows or prefix name `lib` and suffix name `.a` in linux)

Doc From [Compiling with g++](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/99au/unix/g++.html)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out previously, you should replace the -L with -l, however, the previous answer contains a mistake or does not apply anymore on modern installations of mingw-w64. I tested the following myself.

The correct command line argument (link options) should be entirely lowercase as such:

```
-lpsapi
```