# g++ cannot find reference to GetModuleInformation on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, linker, g++

I'm compiling and linking a C++ program with g++ on Windows (MinGW)
The command for compiling looks like this:

```
g++ -c file.cpp -o file.o
```

and the command for linking looks like this:

```
g++ -L. -lPsapi -o file.exe file.o
```

I have a file called `Psapi.lib` in the `.` directory (I copied it from the Windows SKD directory) but it still fails to find a reference for `GetModuleInformation`

PS.: [GetModuleInformation Fails on Linkage in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55637441/getmoduleinformation-fails-on-linkage-in-windows-10) didn't help

Comment: Copy libraries from where they are installed to your project directory is a **really bad idea**. What if your system updates that library? Then you'll still be using the old version. What if it's no longer compatible with your updated computer. Instead tell the compiler where the library is. On MinGW that means using the `-L` option.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to either: (a) define the `PSAPI_VERSION` token (to `1`); or (b) call the function by its 'new' name of `K32GetModuleInformation()`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmoduleinformation):

> If PSAPI_VERSION is 2 or greater, this function is defined as
> K32GetModuleInformation in Psapi.h and exported in Kernel32.lib and
> Kernel32.dll. If PSAPI_VERSION is 1, this function is defined as
> K32GetModuleInformation in Psapi.h and exported in Psapi.lib and
> Psapi.dll as a wrapper that calls K32GetModuleInformation.
>
> Programs that must run on earlier versions of Windows as well as
> Windows 7 and later versions should always call this function as
> K32GetModuleInformation. To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add
> Psapi.lib to the TARGETLIBS macro and compile the program with
> -DPSAPI_VERSION=1. To use run-time dynamic linking, load Psapi.dll.

Comment: So, I've added `#define PSAPI_VERSION 2`, included `Windows.h`, then `Psapi.h` and tried calling `K32GetModuleInformation` instead of `GetModuleInformation` and now I'm getting `'K32GetModuleInformation' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'GetModuleInformation'`

Comment: @CredixYt Then maybe there are issues with your library and/or compiler configurations. It's often tricky using third-party compilers/linkers with newer Windows OS builds.

Comment: It's especially challenging since we don't even know which toolchain you are using. MinGW comes in two flavors: A hopelessly outdated 32-bit version, and a somewhat less outdated 64-bit version.

Comment: I just checked and my MinGW installation directory has a folder called `mingw32` and some files in `bin` are prefixed by `mingw32-` so I'm assuming it is a 32bit installation. Do you think installing the 64bit version could help? I'm compiling and linking a 32bit binary on a 64bit OS, that's why I installed the 32bit version in the first place